# Waiting for DOM update before using jQuery offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got code that shows a hidden element and then gets its size:

```
var div = $('div.foo').show(); // Was hidden.

// Need to wait until the DOM is updated to get its offset
setTimeout(function() {
    var offset = div.offset();
    bar(offset.top, offset.left);
}, 0);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this instead of a deferring the call to `div.offset()` with a `setTimeout` of `0`, or is this best practice? Can I bind do some DOM update event or something else?

Comment: If you don't pass a duration to `.show()`, it'll be a synchronous action which doesn't need a `setTimeout` afaik. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cAmjN/)

Comment: Good observation. So I guess the fact that `offset()` doesn't work _until_ I've let the DOM update means something else is wrong.

Comment: Yup, do some `console.log`ing and you'll see the values are right. It may be something to do with your `bar` function and/or the order you're doing the operations (it usually is), I'll take a look at the problem when you make another question with the isolated problem. `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.show()` without passing a duration parameter is a synchronous action and thus doesn't require a `setTimeout`. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> With no parameters, the `.show()` method is the simplest way to display an element [...]
>
> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially.

If you specify a duration however, you can pass a callback function which will be executed when the animation completes:

```
var div = $('div.foo').show(400, function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    bar(offset.top, offset.left);
});
```