# Does the .show() event (without parameters) happen immediately?

Tags: jquery

If I want something to occur after the .show() event (the one without the parameters & callback), 
Do I need to add the callback function, or is it a Synchronous event ?

Comment: The `show` method it's not a event, You just could add the code after the called to method show before, or add a callback in one of overloads

Comment: Not an exact duplicate as the question is different, but the answer is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12078600/1331430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially.

So the div or whatever is displayed immediately. But you might see some of the old content if you change it after the show method. Usually you want to call the `.show()` when you are done editing the element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. show() means that it will add to your tag style="display: block;" or "display: inline-block" or other depending from the tag type

If you call hide() it will set to your tag style="display: none;"